# Is this space discrete?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let X be a Tychonoff space  such that for any closed set A there exist a continuous function f: X to R such that A=cl(X-Z(f)). Is this space X discrete?

Comment: What is Z(f)?${}$

Comment: @Wojowu I assume Z(f) is the zero set of f.

Comment: The answer is yes and this is a trivial exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume $Z(f)$ indeed means the zero set.

Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. As $X$ is Tychonoff, $A=\{x\}$ is closed, so by assumption there is an $f$ such that $\{x\}=cl(X\setminus Z(f))$. But this clearly implies $X\setminus Z(f)=\{x\}$. Since $Z(f)$ is closed as the preimage of a closed set $\{0\}$, $\{x\}$ is open so $X$ is discrete.

Comment: I do not unterstand how {x}=cl(X-Z(f)) implies X- Z(f)={x}.

Comment: X-Z(f) is an open set.

Comment: @Wojowu why are you answering what is clearly someones pointset topology homework?

Comment: @StevenGubkin To be fair I didn't even notice this is MO, I was answering this from mobile...